# testing component with react-day-picker produce warnings

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-day-picker

What API for dates does react-day-picker use?
I'm mocking Date in my test as

```js
    global.Date = class extends Date {
      constructor(date: string) {
        super(date);
        return date ? this : fromUnixTime(946684800);
      }
    } as DateConstructor;
    global.Date.now = jest.fn(() => 946684800000);
```

here and keep getting console warning: Encountered two children with the same key, 197001.
I see that dates in calendar are actually correct, but aria-label="Thu Jan 01 1970"
Seems that my date mock breaks the library.

Any ideas?

_

Comment: What does your component look like? You're having duplicate keys somewhere in a rendered list.

Comment: It just day picker with wrapper.
there is no such problems if I open this component in browser, or test it without mocking Date object.